# How do I find the URL for a customized embedded Google map?

Tags: google-maps, customization

I'm trying to find the URL for a custom embedded map (not my map -- the one at http://flood.gistda.or.th) so that I can bookmark a link with the zoom and location levels that are useful to me, but I haven't been able to find a link on the map or any info yet on this through various searches.

To clarify, I'm not looking for the original Google map, but a link to the map with all the custom layers of data added on.  In this case, the original link shows a map with all the areas of Thailand that are currently under water, while the original Google map just shows the underlying map data (satellite or street data from Google). (see images below)

I'm looking for a way to see the map with the custom layer of data (within the Google Maps site, I expect is most likely) so that I can save a link to the zoom/location I want and still see the custom layer.  The embedded map doesn't seem to offer this option, and the link to Google Maps gives me the option without the custom layer of data.

#### Map with custom layer:

[Click for full sized version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwu4T.png)

[image]

#### Original Google map:

[Click for full sized version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTrVt.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined in [this Google Maps API blog post](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2006/11/kml-on-google-maps.html), if you have a link to the KML or KMZ file from Google Earth that is layered on their map, all you have to do is enter that link into the search bar in Google Maps, and the map will load with the KML/KMZ data layered over the map.  You can then click on the "link" button on the left-hand side to get a link to your current location and zoom level.

One caveat is that the KML/KMZ data shows up *over top of* the map, not as a part of the map as seen in the screenshot in the original question.

**Map with KML/KMZ data:**

[Click for full sized version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qqUP.png)

[image]

The other caveat is that you need access to their KML/KMZ file in order to use this method.

Answer (score 5):

Click on "Powered by Google" logo which is located on the lower left corner of that map. It will take you to the [original Google map](http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=15.580711,101.096191&spn=5.289574,6.998291&t=u&z=7&key=ABQIAAAASGbUu88CUKyD78STVPTSvBT18f_SG4lHberOoRZBH73UjD5BBhTbihlDMTYGRd-_Jh1TNTiTVTdG3w&mapclient=jsapi&oi=map_misc&ct=api_logo).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @mepher. It's not quite what I was looking for, but I should have clarified a bit better.I'm not looking for the original Google map, but a link to the maps with all the custom layers of data added on.

Comment: I've edited the original question to clarify further.

Comment: There are some KML and SMP files on the left pane. Have you checked them? You can open them in Google Maps software and see if they include the layers.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid going through the software, but I'll give it a look.  Thanks.